# Error(-17994): Invalid arguments for lr_save_string

Tags: performance, loadrunner

I am trying to get the random value from list of data. But I am geting the error(-17994).

```
web_reg_save_param("c_Log",
                   "LB=LogNumber:",
                   "RB=\"",
                   "Ordinal=All",LAST);

lr_save_string(lr_paramarr_random("c_Log"),"randomValue");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the precise ordering in your code then your pseudo array is unlikely to have any values in it until the next page/HTTP request is made.  You would be attempting a random assignment of an empty set.

Try setting your lr_save_string() after the next page load when the c_log array is likely to have some values seeded, assuming the expected page loads correctly

```
web_reg_save_param(...);

web_url(...);

lr_save_string(...);
```